# Parsing file in PHP; how to detect newlines?

Tags: php, parsing, file, newline

I've got a problem where I'm trying to read a text file like this:

```
Joe
Johnson

Linus
Tourvalds
```

and while parsing it in php, I need to be able to detect the newlines. I'm trying to correctly define $newline. I'm looping through the array of lines in the $file variable.

```
while($line = next($file))
    if($line = $newline)
        echo "new line";
```

The problem is that I can't seem to match the newline character. I know that it is actually showing up in the $file array, because this:

```
while($line = next($file))
    echo $line;
```

outputs the file verbatim, with newlines and all. I've already tried "\n", " ", and I'm not sure what to try next. A little help?

Comment: "I'm looping through the array of lines" So you already have the lines of the file split up?

Comment: Exactly.  How did you get the `$file` array in the first place.  And why are you using `next()` instead of a standard `foreach`/`for`? (there are reasons, but not too many)...

Comment: careful using next(), it advances the pointer before returning the element! (you'll miss "joe").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = file("path/to/file.txt");

// Incase you need to call it multiple times ...
function isNewLine($line) {
    return !strlen(trim($line));
}

foreach ($file as $line) {
    if (isNewLine($line)) {
        echo "new line<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work for you?

```
while($line = next($file)) {
    if(in_array($line, array("\r", "\n", "\r\n"))) {
        echo "new line";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution may help you guys. This works if you are parsing csv that is generated from Mac or windows. Reading csv with multilines  created in Mac, gives problem i.e. you cannot read each line in a  loop but all csv data is read as single line.

This problem is solved by following solution:

```
//My CSV contains only one column
$fileHandle = fopen("test.csv",'r');
$codesArray    = array();
count = 0;
while (!feof($fileHandle) ) {
$line = fgetcsv($fileHandle);
if($line[0]!="") {
   $data = str_replace("'", "", (nl2br ($line[0])));
   $dataArray = explode('<br />' ,$data );
   foreach($dataArray as $data) {
       $codesArray[] = trim($data);
   }
}
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($codesArray);
```